# JPanel with hide button in its border to fold or unfold it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, show-hide, folding

I need for a java application a panel with an hide/display button in its "border", which folds or unfolds it.

A description of the effect can be found under [this doc of JDS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/817-7305/gospanel-7/index.html) : "The panel reduces in the direction of the arrow on the hide button. The hide button at the other end of the panel remains visible"; but I need it under Java, not JDS...

Does java have such a panel, or is it to implement by ourself?

Comment: I think you'd need to implement it yourself

Comment: Please have a look at [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), might be this can help a bit :-)

Comment: SlidingLayout really does beautyfull things, but it is too much for my small usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer: Java has native what I need: [JSplitPlane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html)

Comment: +1, never used `JSplitPane`, though my memory got refreshed about its capabilities, as I saw this word in your answer.

Comment: @Olivier Faucheux, could you provide a simple example? I need this feature in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it by setting the bounds of your panel on onclick event of your show/hide button.